# 'Error' message: '‘reverse_lock’ is not a member of ‘boost’'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

file: `file:///opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/server/action_server_base.h`

```
severity: 'Error'
message: '‘reverse_lock’ is not a member of ‘boost’'
at: '256,5'
source: ''

file: 'file:///opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/server/action_server_base.h'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token'
at: '256,60'
source: ''
file: 'file:///opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/server/action_server_base.h'
severity: 'Error'
message: '‘unlocker’ was not declared in this scope'
at: '256,70'
source: ''
```

above is the error when i try to build a package. This is the line where error is occuring:

```
boost::reverse_lock<boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock> unlocker(lock);
```

as i checked my boost version, i've installed boost 1.58.0. Is this ok if i edit the `action_server_bash.h` file? will not it affect latter since this hearder file is default file of actionlib package for ros kinetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285868/%27error%27-message:-%27%E2%80%98reverse_lock%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98boost%E2%80%99%27/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-20**:
Editing that file is not correct; that lock is probably there for a reason, and removing it is likely to cause bugs.

Your error messages look unusual. Which operating system and compiler are you using?

It would also be useful to see the code or a small sample program that demonstrates this error.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-20**:
i am using ubuntu 16.06, kernel version  4.13.0-37 generic, ros kinetic. well i was trying to use [rtt_actionlib_example](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/rtt_ros_examples/tree/master/rtt_actionlib_examples) . But it seems like this package has not been maintained for over3 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in actionlib, not in the tutorial you're following.

It looks like this was fixed in https://github.com/ros/actionlib/pull/95 and released, so the fix will likely go out with the next sync of kinetic.

Sync announcements are posted in the general category on ROS Discourse: https://discourse.ros.org/c/general ; keep an eye on that list for the announcement of the next sync.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-21**:
yes. after i cloned the new repository of actionlib package and build it removing the default one this error has gone. tk